# trouble with multiple $_GET

Tags: php, get

Im using variable `$gallery_name = (isset($_GET['subj']) ? $_GET['subj'] : 'cakes');` for a menu with multiple photo galleries and `$page = (isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1);` for pagination of the selected gallery. When the gallery called 'cakes' is selected, pagination displays pages with images from the gallery, but when any other gallery is selected, clicking on pagination links defaults back to 'cakes' gallery instead of displaying images from the selected gallery. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: You haven't shown us the code where you generate the pagination links!

Comment: Post code? You probably have a hand coded reference to 'cakes' somewhere

Comment: sounds like your not maintaining the values in your url. Make sure your links for the pagination change dependning on the current `subj`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you aren't passing `subj` parameter for galleries pages, should be like:

```
yoursite/page=1&subj=gallery1
```

If it is: `yoursite/page=1` then the gallery will default to cakes. so make sure the link is actually passing the `subj` parameter. Or provide more code so can provide a better answer.

Comment: That is exactly the issue I'm having. I don't know how to pass both parameters at the same time. Clicking on any pagination link erases the ?subj=pancakes from the url and sets ?page=2 When no value is set for ?subj, it defaults back to 'cakes'. I want to preserve 'pancakes' when that gallery is selected but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Ok, well just paste all of your code and we can see what is causing the problem. no worries.

Comment: Make sure your anchor tags for the pagination include the subj in the links url

Comment: Pagination code:    `for($i = $min; $i <= $max; ++$i){
        if($i == $page){
            echo " <span class=\"page\">{$i}</span> ";
 }else{
     echo " <a href=" . $address . "{$i}>{$i}</a> "; 
 }
    }`
Gallery menu: `$gallery_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT gallery_name FROM {$table}";
$gall_names = Photograph::find_by_sql($gallery_sql);
foreach($gall_names as $page){
 $output = "<li><a href=\"index.php?subj=" . $page->gallery_name . "\">"; 
 $output .= " <img src=\"" . $page->image_path() . "\" />";
 $output .= "</a></li>";
 echo $output;`
}

Comment: I figured it out: I had a variable $address = "index.php?page=" which I changed to $address = "index.php?subj=" . $gallery_name . "&page=";